# How can I edit files within encrypted zip files?

Tags: encryption, compression

Currently I can use emacs to edit text files within zip files no problem. I simply get a directory listing from which I can choose the document that I want to edit.

Is there anyway to edit text files that are located within **encrypted** zip files?

I know this is possible with .gpg files, but not so sure about encrypted zip files.